# How to test tizen application on samsung device?

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator, tizen-native-app

I am very new to Tizen SDK. I have just tried to run a sample native app on its emulator, which is running perfectly. I want to test its sample application on my samsung device but don't know how to do this.
Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Is your Samsung device running Tizen? If so, I'd imagine you can launch your app from the IDE, just like you would when using the emulator. If it isn't running Tizen, and the device hasn't been listed as being capable of running Tizen, then you can't do this with your device.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned a native application, so just to clarify, as I understand you mean you want to develop **mobile** applications. Because, as far as I know, there is no way to develop native apps on the Gear.

What's the most important, you need to have a device with Tizen. Few people do. If you only have an Android device it won't work.

For more information about native application programming you can see [developer.tizen.org](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/cover_page.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to request a certificate. You can do it via IDE, or separate mail.

You can get DUID of the Samsumg device you have. They will send you a certificate which gives you the developer privileges on the watch.

1. After that you have to enable USB Debugging on you Gear.
2. Allow unknown sources on Gear Manager on you Phone.
3. Viola! you will see the device listed and you can run your information as you would do for an emulator.

See http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-gear for more information.